# if $u=3^{1/5}$ then $\mathbb Q(u)=\mathbb Q(u²)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

if $u=3^{1/5}$ then $\mathbb Q(u)=\mathbb Q(u²)$

As $u=3^{1/5}$ then elements of $\mathbb Q(u)$ are of the type 
$a+b\,3^{1/5}$ and of $\mathbb Q(u²)$ are $a+b\,9^{1/5}$

Then bases for $\mathbb Q(u)$ are $\{ 1, 3^{1/5} \} $
and for $\mathbb Q(u²)$ are $\{ 1, 9^{1/5}\}$

How they can be equal then ?

Comment: Number fields can have more than one basis.  For instance $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)=\mathbb Q(2\,\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: None of what you call "bases" are such for those extensions of the rationals: both $\;u=\sqrt[5]3\;,\;u^2=\sqrt[5]9\;$ are algebraic numbers of degree higher than two. What can you say, for example, about the polynomial $\;x^5-3\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ ?

Comment: **Hint:**  $u=\frac13u^5 \cdot u = \frac13u^6 \in \mathbb Q(u^2)$.  Now how does that work with your "basis" for $\mathbb Q(u^2)$?

Comment: That's mean that basis for these extensions must be of degree five ?

Comment: Are you talking about $\mathbb{Q}(u)$ or $\mathbb{Q}[u]$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout In this case, they're just the same as $\;u\;$ is algebraic.

Comment: $$\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/5})=\mathbb{Q}(3^{6/5})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(3^{2/5})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(3^{1/5})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... *As $u=3^{1/5}$ then elements of $\mathbb Q(u)$ are of the type 
$a+b\,3^{1/5}$ and of $\mathbb Q(u^2)$ are $a+b\,9^{1/5}$ ...*

This statement is incorrect.  The elements of $\mathbb Q(u)$ are actually of the type $a+b\,3^{1/5}+c\,3^{2/5}+d\,3^{3/5}+e\,3^{4/5}$; those of $\mathbb Q(u^2)$ are of type $a+b\,9^{1/5}+c\,9^{2/5}+d\,9^{3/5}+e\,9^{4/5}$.  Now we note that $9^{1/5} = \,3^{2/5}$, $9^{2/5} = \,3^{4/5}$, $9^{3/5} = \,3^{6/5} = 3 \times \,3^{1/5}$, and $9^{4/5} = \,3^{8/5} = 3 \times \,3^{3/5}$, and we easily see that these two forms both denote the same set of values.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are! Since $\Bbb Q(u)$ is a field, then $u^2$ belongs to $\Bbb Q(u)$, hence all elements of the form $a+bu^2$ belong to $\Bbb Q(u)$; hence $\Bbb Q(u^2)\subseteq \Bbb Q(u)$.

For the other inclusion, observe that $(u^2)^3\in \Bbb Q(u^2)$, because $\Bbb Q(u^2)$ is a field. But $(u^2)^3=u^6=3u$, hence $\Bbb Q(u^2)$ contains all elements of the form $a+bu$, hence $\Bbb Q(u)\subseteq \Bbb Q(u^2)$.

Then $\Bbb Q(u)=\Bbb Q(u^2)$.

Comment: Small nits - $u^6=3u$, and better to use $\subseteq$ etc. Doesn't change anything else though. +1

Comment: Thank for your comment! I edit my post.